# Search with boolean true using thinking sphinx is not working properly, when boolean is false also its showing results

Tags: ruby-on-rails

## this is code in my indices file

```
ThinkingSphinx::Index.define 'cg_user/user', :name => 'reviewer_search', :with => :active_record, :delta => true  do
  indexes profile.interests.interest_name, :as => :interest_name
  has profile(:voluntary_reviewer), as: :profile_voluntary_reviewer, :type=>:boolean
  has id, :as => :user_id
  set_property :field_weights => { :interest_name => 3 }
end
```

## this is my condtion in model

```
CgUser::User.search(search_string,
                    :with => {:profile_voluntary_reviewer => true, 
                    :user_id => probable_matched_name_ids},
                    :indices => ['reviewer_search_core', 
                    'reviewer_search_delta']
                   ).map(&:id).compact
```

Answer (score 0):

Check [How to index boolean column in thinking sphinx using Ruby 1.8.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6443975/how-to-index-boolean-column-in-thinking-sphinx-using-ruby-1-8-7), see if it fixes your issue.

From [docs](https://freelancing-gods.com/thinking-sphinx/indexing.html):

> Known types for real-time indices are: integer, boolean, string, timestamp, float, bigint and json.

You are using SQL backed indexes and `boolean` might not work. Try instead with 0 and 1.

**Attempt #1**

Because you're using SQL backed indices, boolean values are stored in Sphinx same as in your database, 0 and 1.

```
# index
has profile(:voluntary_reviewer), as: :profile_voluntary_reviewer, type: :integer

# model
CgUser::User.search(search_string, with: { profile_voluntary_reviewer: 1 })
```

Comment: i am setting boolean condition for fields not for indexes.

Comment: @MahanteshD It's not talking about the "indexes" macro but the whole 'cg_user/user' index. For SQL backed index, `boolean` for attributes might not work.

Comment: @MahanteshD Updated the answer to use 0 and 1. Please see if it works. Don't forget to reindex.

Comment: i tried with integer value with reindex again i am getting same result, no change. is there any way to do?

Comment: also when add new interest that time also result is not coming, after rebuilding(reindex) only im getting. plz help me out.. Thank you

Comment: @MahanteshD Please update with the sphinx query from your developement.log and the index logs for `reviewer_search_core` (from rake ts:index) AND the result of `CgUser::User.first.profile.voluntary_reviewer`

Comment: the search is working fine but it takes more time when i change voluntary_reviewer  0 to 1, immediately result are not shown. It takes one hour or two hours to show the result. thank you

Comment: @MahanteshD I shouldn't be that slow, I'm at ~ 15 ms tops.